# Cheese sent via mail

Tags: cheese

I received a parcel from Europe with cheese. Unfortunately they sent it via surface. It took 6 weeks over to  Canada.
The Swiss hard cheese was wrapped in plastic foil. No mold has developed and it smells good.
I wonder whether it is safe to eat it?

Comment: If it's a hard dry cheese, the probably. It might even be better know when then they sent it.

Comment: And an answer today is going to be different from one 6 weeks from now -- 6 weeks over the summer is much different than 6 weeks in the middle of winter in rather cold climates.

Comment: Also -- a clarification -- was it a whole wheel, or a cut from a wheel?

Answer (score 3):

Put simply, if it smells/tastes good, cheese is safe to eat.

There are even cheeses which smell horrible which are still safe to eat like this guy: [Époisses de Bourgogne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoisses_cheese)

Comment: Ummm, for starters Listeria doesn't smell

Comment: Is Listeria able to grow in hard cheese? On the other hand, cheese is usually safe to eat even if it smells horrible. That is how cheese is supposed to smell.

Comment: Mold doesn't smell, so how do you know if there's a bit of mold starting to grow that just isn't visible yet? Would that be unsafe?

Comment: So it would seem, but this could equally be true of refrigerated cheese, and that doesn't seem to be a problem...

Comment: @TFD: There should only be a risk of Listeria if it's made from unpasteurized milk.

Comment: @Aaronut Listeria can be picked up from anywhere, it just needs a good host to live on. Cheese (hard or soft) is a good host. Many Listeria outbreaks happen at point of packaging