# Alimunium foil or plastic wrap to send baked cookies via mail

Tags: cookies

I want to send some regular chocolate chip cookies via mail. It would take approx 3 days (2 min, 4 max I'd say) since sent, to get there. Temperatures can get hot now but it's not urgent so I can wait until the weather has a daily max of 26º C, which is nicer than 40. *Dry weather sending, currently unknown if dry or humid weather receiver*.

I have read about the same topic regarding [cookies](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/39632/how-to-ship-holiday-cookies/39653#39653) and [cheese](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30753/cheese-sent-via-mail), and some external sites like [Land o Lake, how to ship cookies](https://www.landolakes.com/expert-advice/how-to-pack-cookies-for-mailing/) and from [better home and gardens](https://www.bhg.com/recipes/desserts/cookies/how-to-mail-cookies/) as well.

I have the feeling **I am not understanding how moisture works or affects cookies** depending on the material used. I thought aluminium foil was used mainly for temperature "insulation", and plastic film wrap to keep moisture/not drying out. Depending on the site of the links above, some mention aluminium foil, others plastic wrap and also "either of them".

I would say that as long as cookies are not VERY dry, they´ll be fine texturewise. The oils inside the cookie and chocolate chips might also help. Before reading the articles, I would have wrapped them in plastic wrap, and wrapped that in aluminium foil.

Does wrapping cookies in **aluminium foil only**, differ on conservation than on **plastic wrap only**? Is using both or only 1 a good idea depending on the weather conditions?

*(I did not add the preservation tag as it is not for long-term, would it be food safety?).*

Comment: It’s probably been a decade since I’ve mailed cookies, and it was generally in December when the temperature were cooler, but I seem to recall that my issue was more about trying to keep them from bouncing around in the package so they came through in reasonable shape.   I think that I put them on a paper plate, wrapped it in foil, added some extra padding (crushed paper?  Recycled bubble wrap?) then put it into a box that it fit snugly inside.

Comment: One of my neighbors  in college got cookies from home which were shipped in a box full of popcorn - that gave them stable packing that was also an additional, slightly cookie-infused treat. If you bagged the cookies I suppose the popcorn could be non-cookie-infused or flavored some other way. I recall them being shipped loose in the popcorn (said college neighbor shared...)

Comment: I would pack them in a tightly sealed tin, with parchment paper and perhaps a bag of silica inside, and the tin would go in a mailer box with some kind of loose pack like bubble wrap. The tins are pretty and useful, as nice as fresh cookies anyway. I am assuming the cookie is some kind of shortbread rather than some fluffy leavened doughy cookie.